# favicon animation

Tags: animation, favicon

While visiting  [Dean Edward's](http://dean.edwards.name) site, I saw that the favicon was animated ;). Cute. But how does one do that?

Comment: It's redrawn by hand several times a second.

Comment: Whatever it is, it doesn't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an animated GIF file.

Comment: yup - http://dean.edwards.name/about/#q100